# Dynamically add Image into asp.net c# gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I would like to display image inside a gridview. My gridview is being filled like This:
Front:

```
        <asp:GridView 
    ID="GridViewProduct"
    runat="server" 
    CellPadding="4" 
    GridLines="Horizontal"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    width="1020"
    onrowcommand="GridViewCase_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="IDKolonne" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="40px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"/>
         <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="idimg" NullImageUrl="images/thumbs/2.jpg">
            <ControlStyle Height="40px" Width="40px" />
            </asp:ImageField>

            <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Image" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  ImageUrl="~/img/trash.png" commandname="Del" text="Slet Produkt" HeaderText="Slet Produkt"/>
            <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Image" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  ImageUrl="~/img/change.png" commandname="Select" text="Se / Ret" HeaderText="Se / Ret"/>
        </Columns> 
    </asp:GridView>
```

As you see I am able of inserting image static. I would like to ad image from my db referring to ID. My gridview is builded like this:

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(System.Int32));
    table.Columns.Add("idimg", typeof(System.Drawing.Image));

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = galFac.getCurrentUsersElements(3);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(item["Id"]);
        }

        GridViewProduct.DataSource = table;
        GridViewProduct.DataBind();

        GridViewProduct.UseAccessibleHeader = true;            
    }
```

How will this be possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you save images in database or image URL's in database and what database are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. I saved image URL

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass "image path" as string parameter to gridview datasource and use the following asp:Image on your gridview

```
<asp:Image id="abc" ImageUrl =<%#Eval("column_name_image"))%>
```

the aspx.cs code is like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(System.Int32));
table.Columns.Add("column_name_image", typeof(string));

.....
.....
.....

GridViewProduct.DataSource = table;
GridViewProduct.DataBind();
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob. Am i not going to bind Column with ID? : table.Columns.Add("abc", typeof(string)); AND. Am i going to generate a string name in foreach for <%#Eval("column_name_image"))%>. I suppose the asp Image control is going to runat="Server". THANKS FOR HELPING ME OUT.